# I am using Alpha Vantage API to try and pull daily stock info. I am really new to using APIs and don't know what I am doing wrong

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, alpha-vantage

So I am using c# xamarin and making a basic stock app that can pull stock quotes using the Alpha Vantage API. I have what I thought might work but it isn't working at all. Yes this is a school project so I don't expect people to just do it. The purpose of this app is to use the API and I need to show the data that it provides after the user enters in a stock symbol from the first page of the app. I need to send that symbol with the api and I am not sure I am pulling in JSON object and I don't know how to get to each field in the object when I do retrieve the JSON correctly.This code is what im trying and I am not getting any information populated into any of my textViews.

```
namespace Stock_Quote
{
    [Activity(Label = "StockInfoActivity1")]
    public class StockInfoActivity1 : Activity
    {
        private ISharedPreferences prefs = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("APP_DATA", FileCreationMode.Private);
        TextView txtSymbol, txtOpen, txtClose, txtHigh, txtLow, txtVolume;
        string webservice_url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=";

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_stock_info);
            txtSymbol = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtSymbol);
            txtOpen = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtOpen);
            txtClose = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtClose);
            txtHigh = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtHigh);
            txtLow = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtLow);
            txtVolume = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtVolume);
            string current = prefs.GetString("current", "no stok symbol found");

            //txtSymbol.Text = current;

            try
            {
                webservice_url = webservice_url + current + "&apikey=AVALIDAPIKEY";
                Uri url = new Uri(webservice_url);
                var webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);

                if (webRequest != null)
                {

                    webRequest.Method = "GET";
                    webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

                    //Get the response 
                    WebResponse wr = webRequest.GetResponseAsync().Result;
                    Stream receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream);

                    Stock currentStockInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Stock>(reader.ReadToEnd());

                    if (currentStockInfo.RestResponse.result == null)
                    {
                        txtSymbol.Text = "No stock found";
                    }
                    else
                    {                        
                        txtSymbol.Text = current;
                        txtOpen.Text = currentStockInfo.RestResponse.stockInfo.Open;
                        txtClose.Text = currentStockInfo.RestResponse.stockInfo.Close;
                        txtHigh.Text = currentStockInfo.RestResponse.stockInfo.High;
                        txtLow.Text = currentStockInfo.RestResponse.stockInfo.Low;
                        txtVolume.Text = currentStockInfo.RestResponse.stockInfo.Volume;
                    }


                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    public class Result
    {
        public string Information { get; set; }
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
        public string Last { get; set; }
        public string Size { get; set; }
        public string TimeZone { get; set; }
    }

    public class StockInfo
    {
        public string Open { get; set; }
        public string High { get; set; }
        public string Low { get; set; }
        public string Close { get; set; }
        public string Volume { get; set; }
    }

    public class RestResponse
    {       
        public Result result { get; set; }
        public StockInfo stockInfo { get; set; }
    }

    public class Stock
    {
        public RestResponse RestResponse { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

First off, thanks for pasting your code, that's super helpful!

As for your question, it would be easier for us if you were more specific as to what is happening. "I just have no idea what I am doing wrong or how to go about getting it to work" doesn't give me a good idea of where to look for a problem.

In short, I want to know:

1. What action you're taking
2. What result you're expecting
3. What result you're actually getting.

Comment: Also, when you're posting code that uses API keys, don't include the keys in your post!

Comment: I edited the question and that you for the tip of not displaying API key..

Comment: OK, so now you need to debug your code.  First, is your HTTP request returning valid JSON?  Second, is it getting deserialized correctly into your Stock object?  Third, is the UI getting updated with the data from Stock?  You need to determine which step is broken, then figure out why, and then fix it.  Just from looking at your code I don't see an obvious bug.

Comment: Firstly , can you get response info of `currentStockInfo `,and is there any log with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON that's being returned from that endpoint doesn't quite match your model.

Here's the line where you tell your program how to parse the response:

Stock currentStockInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(reader.ReadToEnd());

...but the response looks like this:

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2018-12-10 16:00:02",
        "4. Output Size": "Compact",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2018-12-10": {
            "1. open": "104.8000",
            "2. high": "107.9800",
            "3. low": "103.8900",
            "4. close": "107.5900",
            "5. volume": "39050766"
        },
        "2018-12-07": {
            "1. open": "108.3800",
            "2. high": "109.4500",
            "3. low": "104.3000",
            "4. close": "104.8200",
            "5. volume": "45044937"
        }...
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

}

You're trying to turn this entire response into one `Stock` object, which isn't going to work. The response isn't a `Stock`, it's a response with 2 objects, one of which has a lot of `Stock` objects.

You *could* try to create a model for this*, but I'd recommend turning this entire response into a `JObject` (another object in NewtonSoft JSON.Net).

Here's a DotNetFiddle I put together to demonstrate how it works.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/Iz8UsD

Let me know if I can add anything more helpful.

EDIT: * You can probably get a strongly typed model to work here,the trouble is that each `Stock` has a different JSON name. I don't know how to get the parser to parse each as a `Stock` while still keeping the data around. I'll have to play with that tonight.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I am going to try your advise. So I am trying to create a container for all the objects to go into and then pull data from an object in the container?

Comment: Joe, I am using                                                                                                                                                string currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
 txtViewDisplay.Text = jobj["Time Series (Daily)"][currentDate]["1. open"].ToString() to make it work good enough to get me by for now on the project.

Comment: Joe, your code on dotnetfiddle returns an 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error.

Answer (score 2):

The issue as explained by Joe is the shape of the JSON returned does not allow for an easy mapping to a C# object.

Here is an easier/quicker way of retrieving stock prices from AlphaVantage using C#.

It involves calling the standard API price endpoint but adding '&datatype=csv' as a URL parameter. The format of the response makes it easy to map to a C# Poco object. In the example below, I simply map it to a AlphaVantageData object.

Sample code below. You can run this code live within Gystlin [here](https://gistlyn.com/?gist=099fff06d515a39964932e6eafded243)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.Text;

public class AlphaVantageData
{
     public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
     public decimal Open { get; set; }

     public decimal High { get; set; }
     public decimal Low { get; set; }

     public decimal Close { get; set; }
     public decimal Volume { get; set; }
}

 // retrieve monthly prices for Microsoft
 var symbol = "MSFT";
 var monthlyPrices = $"https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_MONTHLY&symbol={symbol}&apikey=demo&datatype=csv"
            .GetStringFromUrl().FromCsv<List<AlphaVantageData>>();

 monthlyPrices.PrintDump();

 // some simple stats
 var maxPrice = monthlyPrices.Max(u => u.Close);
 var minPrice = monthlyPrices.Min(u => u.Close);
```

Comment: There are some items from the api that are only provided in json format.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this response because I have working code that parses from AlphaVantage Time Series (Daily), into a list of stock quotes. It then does some comparison of the quotes, looking for pivot points. That part needs work, but the List is being fetched correctly from the daily feed.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;

namespace StockQuotes
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<string> quoteTickerSymbols = new List<string>();

            if (args.Length < 1)
            { quoteTickerSymbols.Add("msft"); }
            else
            {
                string[] data = args[0].Split(',');
                quoteTickerSymbols.Add(data.ToString());
            }

            //please use your own API key.
            string APIKey = "";
            string response = "";
            string nameOfStock = "";
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            List<StockQuote> quotes = new List<StockQuote>();

            for (int i = 0; i < quoteTickerSymbols.Count;)
            {
                sb.Append($"https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY&symbol=");
                sb.Append(quoteTickerSymbols[i]);
                sb.Append("&apikey=");
                sb.Append(APIKey);

                string request = sb.ToString();

                response = client.GetStringAsync(request).Result;
                JObject jsonData = JObject.Parse(response);

                nameOfStock = quoteTickerSymbols[i];
                try
                {
                    foreach (JToken item in jsonData.SelectTokens("['Time Series (Daily)']"))
                    {
                        foreach (var datedCollection in item.Children().Children())
                        {
                            sb.Clear();
                            string[] pathArray = datedCollection.Path.Split('.');

                            // the date that's after the Time Series (Daily) part of the path
                            sb.Append(pathArray[1]);

                            DataSetByDay dataSet = datedCollection.ToObject<DataSetByDay>();

                            var quote = datedCollection.Select(x => new StockQuote()
                            {
                                Name = nameOfStock,
                                date = Convert.ToDateTime(sb.ToString()),
                                open = dataSet.open,
                                high = dataSet.high,
                                low = dataSet.low,
                                close = dataSet.close,
                                volume = dataSet.volume
                            });

                            quotes.Add(quote.First());
                            dataSet = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {

                    // write out the issue and then skip the entry.
                    Console.WriteLine(err.Message, err.InnerException, err.Source);
                    i++;
                }

                // move to next token
                i++;

                // at the end, compare the quotes.
                for (int j = 0; j < quotes.Count() - 4; j++)
                {
                    if (quotes[j].open > quotes[j + 1].high && quotes[j].close < quotes[j + 1].low)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", quotes[j].Name);
                        Console.WriteLine("Pivot downside {0}", quotes[j].date);
                    }
                    if (quotes[j].open < quotes[j + 1].low && quotes[j].close > quotes[j + 1].high)
                    {
                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", quotes[j].Name);
                        Console.WriteLine("Pivot upside {0}", quotes[j].date);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is also needed. To store the information.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

namespace StockQuotes
{
    // each daily record from the website
    internal class DataSetByDay
    {
        [JsonProperty("1. open")]
        public decimal open { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("2. high")]
        public decimal high { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("3. low")]
        public decimal low { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("4. close")]
        public decimal close { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("5. volume")]
        public long volume { get; set; }
    }

    //this would append the date and the name of the stock to the time series.
    internal class StockQuote : DataSetByDay
    {
       public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
    }
}
```